# join on list of objects with sub query of list of objects

Tags: linq, join, subquery

Would appreciate some help on this

objects

Vendor 
string VendorID
List VendorSets

VendorSet
string VendorSetID
List VendorSetMembers

VendorSetMember
string VendorSetID
string VendorID

Using Linq  -- What I need is a way to get a list of all the VendorSets any vendor is in.  Not sure how to sub query the list of vendorsetmember for the matching vendorid and return the corresponding vendorset as a list of vendorsets in the vendor object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join vs. sub-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)

Comment: Have you you read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Research the other join and sub query questions first and learn from them.

Comment: i am having issues getting it to work in linq  and yes i did look through other question